# ntpd says it can't open /var/log/ntpd.log even though the file is owned by ntp:ntp, what gives?

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, ntp

I have three Ubuntu servers, one of which is able to save its log in the `/var/log/ntp.log` file, the other two are not.

The configuration looks like this in all of them (clearly uncommented):

```
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

Here is how the file looks:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/ntp.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ntp ntp 0 Jul 21 13:13 /var/log/ntp.log
```

Yet, I get this error on two machines:

> ```
> Jul 21 13:19:01 ubuntu ntpd[18128]: Cannot open logfile /var/log/ntp.log: Permission denied
> ```

What else can I do than creating the file and making sure it's owned by ntp in terms of *permissions*?

```
touch /var/log/ntp.log
chown ntp:ntp /var/log/ntp.log
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with apparmor (i.e. the computer without apparmor is the one that works as expected), but I don't see any reason why it would fail.

The `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd` file says:

[...snip...]
/var/log/ntp w,
/var/log/ntp.log w,
/var/log/ntpd w,
[...snip...]

I can see a `DENIED` error from apparmor, but it doesn't seem to be related:

> Jul 21 13:33:50 ubuntu kernel: [369654.558541] audit: type=1400 audit(1626899630.124:990): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ope
> n" profile="/usr/sbin/ntpd" name="/snap/bin/" pid=19628 comm="ntpd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

As we can see, it tried to open `/snap/bin`, not `/var/log/ntp.log`. Just in case I tried to change the `ntp.log` permissions to `rw` instead of just `w` and it made no difference.

Also I want to clearly state that I'm not use a snap package:

```
$ dpkg -l ntp
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-===================================================================
ii  ntp                             1:4.2.8p10+dfsg-5ubu amd64                Network Time Protocol daemon and utility programs
```

Various Posts I've found which, so far, have not help:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1055736/ntpd-permission-denied-writing-to-var-log-ntpstats-statsdir-directory
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116591/why-am-i-getting-apparmor-error-messages-in-the-syslog-about-ntp-and-ldap
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor

---

```
$ bash pathlld /var/log/ntp.log 
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Jun 24 06:42 /
/dev/sdb3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 May 12  2020 /var
/dev/mapper/users-var on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
drwxrwxr-x 26 root syslog 4096 Jul 21 13:29 /var/log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ntp ntp 0 Jul 21 13:13 /var/log/ntp.log
```

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: Cool, but that didn't help...

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and show us, properly formatted, `sudo ./pathlld /var/log/ntpd.log`, and explain how it "didn't help".

Comment: @waltinator "didn't help" -> it's still not sending the log data to the `ntp.log` file. (notice that you can't have the 'd' in `ntp.log` since that's forbidden by apparmor; that said, it had the 'd' at first and it wasn't working either.)